# Importing C4.5 file to R dataframe

Tags: r, dataset

I want to convert the input data available as C4.5 file format into a R data frame.

The data set can be downloaded from the following link
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/communities/

and is avaialble as .NAMES and .DATA files.

My approach was to convert it to a csv file using WEKA and then import the csv file into R. Could not do it as WEKA detected a error while parsing the C4.5 file.

Can some one point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
URL <- 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/communities/communities.data'
data <- read.table(URL, sep = ',',  na.strings = '?')
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to import the dat. to R. For getting the factor names, i downloaded the .NAME file and separated the factor names into a column in cvs and then read the cvs file to get the factor names as a vector..